Fetch mail using @googleapis/gmail and service account
I have the following code:
import * as gmail from "@googleapis/gmail";

const serviceAccount = {
  type: "...",
  project_id: "...",
  private_key_id: "...",
  private_key: "...",
  client_email: "...",
  client_id: "...",
  auth_uri: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  token_uri: "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  auth_provider_x509_cert_url: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  client_x509_cert_url: "...",
  universe_domain: "googleapis.com",
};

export class GmailService {
  private _userEmail: string = "person@mydomain.com";

  constructor() {}

  // Use access token to call Gmail API
  async fetchEmail() {
    const auth = new gmail.auth.GoogleAuth({
      credentials: serviceAccount,
      // keyFile: "/path/to/your-secret-key.json",
      scopes: ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly"],
    });
    const res = gmail.gmail({ version: "v1", auth });
    const messages = await res.users.messages
      .list({
    userId: this._userEmail,
      })
      .catch((e) => e);
    console.log(messages.response.data.error.errors);
  }
}

When I run it I get:
[
  {
    message: 'Precondition check failed.',
    domain: 'global',
    reason: 'failedPrecondition'
  }
]

In order to make sure the service account works I have:

Provisioned the account in google cloud
Gone to Google workspace admin > Security > API controls > Domain-wide delegation and setup domain wide delegation for the user name in my serviceAccount.client_email variable.

Am I missing something? I thought this would be enough to work.
